# gdk-pixbuf-csource tool

Tags: gstreamer

When i tried to install gsteditor-0.10.3.2 in my ubuntu 10.10,en error like this appeared in the termina window
configure: error: 
*** You need the gdk-pixbuf-csource tool which is installed
*** from GTK+ 2.0's gdk-pixbuf.

---

*** Either the location where you installed your GTK+ 2.0 is**
 not in your PATH or something is screwed up with your
** GTK+ 2.0 installation
i couldnot find help from somewhere else.. i am totally new to ubuntu and desperately in ned of helpp

Answer (score 8):

Just type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

You should get `gtk-pixbuf-csource`.

Comment: ..which you can find out by searching package contents on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gdk-pixbuf-csource&mode=exactfilename&suite=artful&arch=any)